# Вопрос о тексте в TextView

Tags: android

Как можно менять цвет, размер и жирность текста программно(через java-код), не прибегая к android:textSize и android:color и при этом создавая каждый раз новые TextView?  Использую данный метод:

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        text.setText("Простой текст")
```

Answer (score 5):

1.Цвет: `text.setTextColor(Color.RED);`

2.Размер: `text.setTextSize(100);`

3.Жирность: `text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);`

Comment: А можно несколько раз изменить размер одного textview? Т,е некоторая часть текста одного размера а вторая часть того же textview другого размера?

Comment: можно, через SpannableString, например так: mySpanString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.5f), from, to, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); txt.setText(mySpanString);

Answer (score 4):

Я правильно понял, что надо Вам это

```
TextView textV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.<id вашего TextView>);
textV.setTextColor(Color.RED);
textV.setBackgroundColor(Color.Black);
```

ну и как ниже

```
textV.setTextSize(100);
textV.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: А похожим способом можно изменить размер шрифта и его жирность?

Comment: подобным образом можно изменить все что угодно, это во многих языках так

Comment: А изменить эти данные мы можем только один раз или же можно сделать textview, содержащий текст разных размеров?

Comment: изменение данных применяется к текущему объекту, если вы укажите новый формат для того же объекта то он как правило сотрет предыдущий это как: x = 1, x = 3 - > ответ x ,в конце операции будет хранить 3

Answer (score 1):

Возможно автор вопроса имел ввиду внутри TextView иметь форматирование текста. В этом случае можно использовать:

```
mytextview.setText(Html.fromHtml("Пример <b>моего текста</b>"));
```

Будет выглядеть так: Пример **моего текста**
С текстом можно делать почти все, что угодно.